# How to relate two rows with cyclic relationship in the same table in sql?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table on MS SQL Server 2008 R2 that consists of the following data:

```
+------+-------+-------------+----------+
| id   | type  | refer_to_id | group_id |
+------+-------+-------------+----------+
| 224  |     2 | 225         |          |
| 225  |     2 | 224         |          |
| 253  |     1 | 288         |          |
| 288  |     1 | 253         |          |
| 647  |     2 | ---         |          |
| 666  |     1 | 647         |          |
| 667  |     1 | 647         |          |
| 668  |     1 | 647         |          |
| 436  |     1 | ---         |          |
| 438  |     2 | 436         |          |
| 695  |     2 | 436         |          |
| 699  |     2 | 436         |          |
| 512  |     2 | ---         |          |
| 321  |     1 | ---         |          |
+------+-------+-------------+----------+
```

I need to update the column "group_id" as following:

```
+------+-------+-------------+----------+
| id   | type  | refer_to_id | group_id |
+------+-------+-------------+----------+
| 224  |     2 | 225         | 224      |
| 225  |     2 | 224         | 224      |
| 253  |     1 | 288         | 253      |
| 288  |     1 | 253         | 253      |
| 647  |     2 | ---         | 647      |
| 666  |     1 | 647         | 647      |
| 667  |     1 | 647         | 647      |
| 668  |     1 | 647         | 647      |
| 436  |     1 | 438         | 436      |
| 438  |     2 | 436         | 436      |
| 695  |     2 | 436         | 436      |
| 699  |     2 | 436         | 436      |
| 512  |     2 | ---         | 512      |
| 321  |     1 | ---         | 321      |
+------+-------+-------------+----------+
```

I would like the `group_id` to be the `MIN(ID)` between related rows.
Unfortunately I have cyclic relationship so I become crazy on writing T-SQL update statement.

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand correctly your use case, but maybe you could simply do the update comparing `refer_to_id` and `id` columns.

```
update my_table
set group_id =  case when refer_to_id > id then id 
                    when  refer_to_id < id then refer_to_id 
                    else id 
                end
```

This is really basic and will not fix your issue if you have complex dependencies (line #1 referring to line #2 referring to line #3 etc...).

Comment: thank you! Fortunately I don't have complex dependacies. I just modified your code to handle case when refer_to_id is empty.

Comment: In practice, the data represent the relations among patients of two different clinical studies (the "type"), and purpose of the "group_id" column is to group them in the same family.

Comment: @mtallon : the case when refer_to_id is null is already handled by the else clause. But indeed you need to add the case when the field is blank or contains three dashes.

Comment: yes I know. data above was just a simplified sample. in real data the field is never blank and when it is "not answered" the value is -1, so I just have to handle this case. thank you again!